# How to implement stoppable and cancellable folder synchronization in java?

Tags: java, synchronization, rollback, cancellation

I have two directory structures and need to synchronize them, i.e. copy into the target folder the files and folders from the source folder that are new or changed and delete the files and folders in the target that are not present in the source. However, this process is required to have a "Cancel" button, which will stop it from executing and roll back all the changes. I searched around and found this code, but my understanding of how it actually works is hazy at best.

```
//$Id: FileHelper.java 15522 2008-11-05 20:06:43Z hardy.ferentschik $

//Revised from hibernate search util
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * Utility class for synchronizing files/directories.
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 * @author Sanne Grinovero
 * @author Hardy Ferentschik
 */
public abstract class FileHelper {

  private static final int FAT_PRECISION = 2000;
  public static final long DEFAULT_COPY_BUFFER_SIZE = 16 * 1024 * 1024; // 16 MB


  public static boolean areInSync(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    if ( source.isDirectory() ) {
      if ( !destination.exists() ) {
        return false;
      }
      else if ( !destination.isDirectory() ) {
        throw new IOException(
            "Source and Destination not of the same type:"
                + source.getCanonicalPath() + " , " + destination.getCanonicalPath()
        );
      }
      String[] sources = source.list();
      Set<String> srcNames = new HashSet<String>( Arrays.asList( sources ) );
      String[] dests = destination.list();

      // check for files in destination and not in source
      for ( String fileName : dests ) {
        if ( !srcNames.contains( fileName ) ) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      boolean inSync = true;
      for ( String fileName : sources ) {
        File srcFile = new File( source, fileName );
        File destFile = new File( destination, fileName );
        if ( !areInSync( srcFile, destFile ) ) {
          inSync = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      return inSync;
    }
    else {
      if ( destination.exists() && destination.isFile() ) {
        long sts = source.lastModified() / FAT_PRECISION;
        long dts = destination.lastModified() / FAT_PRECISION;
        return sts == dts;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void synchronize(File source, File destination, boolean smart) throws IOException {
    synchronize( source, destination, smart, DEFAULT_COPY_BUFFER_SIZE );
  }

  public static void synchronize(File source, File destination, boolean smart, long chunkSize) throws IOException {
    if ( chunkSize <= 0 ) {
      System.out.println("Chunk size must be positive: using default value." );
      chunkSize = DEFAULT_COPY_BUFFER_SIZE;
    }
    if ( source.isDirectory() ) {
      if ( !destination.exists() ) {
        if ( !destination.mkdirs() ) {
          throw new IOException( "Could not create path " + destination );
        }
      }
      else if ( !destination.isDirectory() ) {
        throw new IOException(
            "Source and Destination not of the same type:"
                + source.getCanonicalPath() + " , " + destination.getCanonicalPath()
        );
      }
      String[] sources = source.list();
      Set<String> srcNames = new HashSet<String>( Arrays.asList( sources ) );
      String[] dests = destination.list();

      //delete files not present in source
      for ( String fileName : dests ) {
        if ( !srcNames.contains( fileName ) ) {
          delete( new File( destination, fileName ) );
        }
      }
      //copy each file from source
      for ( String fileName : sources ) {
        File srcFile = new File( source, fileName );
        File destFile = new File( destination, fileName );
        synchronize( srcFile, destFile, smart, chunkSize );
      }
    }
    else {
      if ( destination.exists() && destination.isDirectory() ) {
        delete( destination );
      }
      if ( destination.exists() ) {
        long sts = source.lastModified() / FAT_PRECISION;
        long dts = destination.lastModified() / FAT_PRECISION;
        //do not copy if smart and same timestamp and same length
        if ( !smart || sts == 0 || sts != dts || source.length() != destination.length() ) {
          copyFile( source, destination, chunkSize );
        }
      }
      else {
        copyFile( source, destination, chunkSize );
      }
    }
  }

  private static void copyFile(File srcFile, File destFile, long chunkSize) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream( srcFile );
      FileChannel iChannel = is.getChannel();
      os = new FileOutputStream( destFile, false );
      FileChannel oChannel = os.getChannel();
      long doneBytes = 0L;
      long todoBytes = srcFile.length();
      while ( todoBytes != 0L ) {
        long iterationBytes = Math.min( todoBytes, chunkSize );
        long transferredLength = oChannel.transferFrom( iChannel, doneBytes, iterationBytes );
        if ( iterationBytes != transferredLength ) {
          throw new IOException(
              "Error during file transfer: expected "
                  + iterationBytes + " bytes, only " + transferredLength + " bytes copied."
          );
        }
        doneBytes += transferredLength;
        todoBytes -= transferredLength;
      }
    }
    finally {
      if ( is != null ) {
        is.close();
      }
      if ( os != null ) {
        os.close();
      }
    }
    boolean successTimestampOp = destFile.setLastModified( srcFile.lastModified() );
    if ( !successTimestampOp ) {
      System.out.println("Could not change timestamp for {}. Index synchronization may be slow. " + destFile );
    }
  }

  public static void delete(File file) {
    if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
      for ( File subFile : file.listFiles() ) {
        delete( subFile );
      }
    }
    if ( file.exists() ) {
      if ( !file.delete() ) {
        System.out.println( "Could not delete {}" + file );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code functions as advertised, but what I'm unsure about is:

1. How would I implement the cancelling? The best I can come up with is introducing a synchronizationCancelled boolean variable that will be set to true upon pressing the cancel button and lacing synchronize() with checks that will stop it from executing if false.
2. How would I implement the rollback? The best idea I can come up with is copying over the changed/deleted/new files somewhere aside and then copying them back to their original locations once cancelled.

Are my guesses actually the right ways to do it, are there some caveats to them that I'm not aware of, or should cancellation and rollback be implemented completely differently in this case?

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to keep the files located in the source folder, I think , it will be simple to copy them in a third folder (let's call it tmp), and if the user does not cancel the operation, just rename it to target, otherwise delete it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The boolean is kind of alright but not if you ever consider using it multithreaded especially since the whole class ist static. In this case you should use a token (just some object) with a synchronized boolean property to avoid any problems. Afaik there is no standardized class or approach.
2. You have to somehow store a copy. For few and small files you can simply use the memory but for a larger amount or size you will have to store the files somewhere in the file system prior to synchronizing. But you only need to copy the files you want to synchronize so it is dependent on the process.
   Like hasnae proposed you can rename them after/beforehand for convinience.
   But in the end there is always a time as small as it may be where it is still operating and cancelling won't be an option anymore.

Maybe a little illustration for 2.:
File A to File B

Way one:

```
Store B in memory -> copy A to B -> Point of save return -> Delete B in memory
Rollback memory B to file B
```

Way two:

```
Store B in C > copy A to B -> Point of save return -> Delete C
Rollback copy C to B
```

Way three (hasnae):

```
Copy A in C > rename B to D -> rename/move C to B -> Point of save return -> Delete D
Rollback delete C
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something very similar a few years ago and it has proven to work very well over the years.

Our synchronization was much more complex as it involved more steps (dependency management, registration, pause/resume functionality, rollback with de-registration and cleaning), but I believe the same solution applies in your case.

1. You got it right. Have multiple thread workers dequeuing your items (files) and at every iteration check the pause flag. Sleep/Wake them when necessary.
2. For us it was better to use the file extensions as it also allowed for versioning. 
   So for example you end up having:

   - destination.exe (old file)
   - destination.exe.v2 (new file)

     or:
   - destination.exe (new file)
   - destination.exe.bak (old file)

On completion just apply the final names (confirm sync/rollback).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to do the following

1. Determine the list of unchanged files
2. Determine the list of deleted files
3. Determine the files that you have to copy

Once you have these, on the same drive volume as the directory you are syncing do, create a new directory.

For the list of files that are unchanged, create a hard link for the same file to the new directory (with the same name, and the same relative position in the tree).

For the deleted files, you do nothing.

For the new files, you simply copy them up to the new directory structure.

When all completed, rename the old directory to something temporary. Rename the new directory to the original directory name. Then, finally, delete the old directory.

If you ever need to "rollback", simply delete the new directory.

The benefit of this is for the files that have not changed, no new disk space is consumed, and no time is lost copying data you already have. The hard link is basically another pointer to the same data. This is why you must do this on the same drive volume, it's a directory trick. You never lose the deleted files (you simply don't link them), and then you just have you new copies in the new folder.

So in the end, the only file copying that is done is the files that changed.